# Software android inspection

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I need to check and debug the source code of web pages on my smart phone.

I would like to know if there is a way to do that, as it is possible on desktop browser with **Firebug** on **Firefox** on desktop.

I have problem with CSS/HTML/JavaScript on the native browser of android on my Galaxy Prime so I need to check the code in real time to see where the problem come from.

Has anyone a solution to do that an application or something ?

Here is the list  of software / app I have tried so far:

- Weinre
- SideSync with HTML Source Viewer
- Edge Inspect CC
- PhoneGap
- ADB de GoogleChromes